# How best will one extract confidence intervals in PropCIs package using mutate function?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have tried to extract the confidence intervals generated using PropCIs package but I do not seem to get it right. Any assistance? I get this warning :

Warning messages:

1: Problem with `mutate()` input `conf.low`.
i the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
i Input `conf.low` is `PropCIs::exactci(n, N, 0.95)[["conf.int"]][[1]]`.
i The error occurred in group 1: trt = "Drug A".

I have also tried using the map2 but could not get my head around it.

```
# Purpose:  Calculate exact (Clopper-Pearson) confidence intervals

# Libraries ----

library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
library(PropCIs)

# Problem: I would like to get the exact confidence intervals based on the
# proportions


# Code ----

trial %>%
  filter(!is.na(response)) %>%
  mutate(trt = as.factor(trt),
         response  = as.factor(response)) %>%
  group_by(trt) %>%
  count(response) %>%
  mutate( N = sum(n),
          conf.low = exactci(n, N, 0.95) [["conf.int"]][[1]],
          conf.high = exactci(n, N, 0.95) [["conf.int"]][[2]])

exactci(67, 95, 0.95) [["conf.int"]][[1]] # 0.60
exactci(67, 95, 0.95) [["conf.int"]][[2]] # 0.79

# Any way o doing in map2?
map2(c(67, 28), c(95, 95), ~exactci(.x, .y, 0.95))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `rowwise()` and another mutate in dplyr and it should work fine, The warning

> the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

is quite common and shouldn't be ignored, it means that the function is not supporting a vectorized operation(in this case a rowwise operation) but user want it to do it. So  you are providing many inputs and expecting many outputs or in other words you want to perform an operation taking one input at a time get one output at a time.
One can try this workaround:

```
library(gtsummary)
library(tidyverse)
library(PropCIs)
trial %>%
  filter(!is.na(response)) %>%
  mutate(trt = as.factor(trt),
         response  = as.factor(response)) %>%
  group_by(trt) %>%
  count(response)  %>% 
  mutate( N = sum(n)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(conf.low = exactci(n, N, 0.95) [["conf.int"]][[1]],
         conf.high = exactci(n, N, 0.95) [["conf.int"]][[2]])
```

I hope below is your expected output:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
# Rowwise:  trt
#  trt    response     n     N conf.low conf.high
#  <fct>  <fct>    <int> <int>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 Drug A 0           67    95    0.603     0.794
#2 Drug A 1           28    95    0.206     0.397
#3 Drug B 0           65    98    0.561     0.756
#4 Drug B 1           33    98    0.244     0.439
```

Comment: Thank you so much @PKumar. This really helps even in future similar warnings! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Through great insight from a colleague, I realized it is possible to achieve the same thing using **DescTools** package. Below is the solution.

```
# Use DescTools
library(DescTools)

trial %>%
  filter(!is.na(response)) %>%
  mutate(trt = as.factor(trt),
         response  = as.factor(response)) %>%
  group_by(trt) %>%
  count(response) %>%
  mutate( N = sum(n),
          ci = Format(BinomCI(n, N, 0.95, method = "clopper-pearson"))) %>%
  dtplyr::lazy_dt() %>% as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(ci.lwr.ci = round(as.numeric(ci.lwr.ci) * 100,1),
         ci.upr.ci = round(as.numeric(ci.upr.ci) * 100,1),
         ci.est = as.numeric(ci.est) *100) %>%
  mutate(ci = str_glue("{ci.lwr.ci}",  "{ci.upr.ci}", .sep = ","))

exactci(67, 95, 0.95) [["conf.int"]][[1]] # 0.6029022
exactci(33, 98, 0.95) [["conf.int"]][[1]] # 0.2443701
```